# working with angular 4 , node js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express

Am new to angular and node js. Am trying to create one project  using  Mysql, angular 4, node js and express(M*EAN). Can anyone suggest a good tutorial for creating app using mysql,node js and angular 4 ?

Comment: why angular 4 and not 5?

Comment: For MYSQL you could use Sequelize: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize
You'll find plenty of tutorials on Express and Angular out there including in the official docs. Angular having in my opinion the steepest learning curve as you have to put your hands on ES6, TypeScript, RXJS plus the framework itself at the same time

Comment: Is sequelize is the best ORM for nodejs?